# Location Based WIldcard Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, geolocation, location

How can one set up a location-based wildcard redirect with two different regions? Specifically focussed on a PHP/LAMP set-up, with multiple Wordpress sites.

So there are two domains:

```
http://website.com/ --- Serves Australia
http://website.com/international/ --- Serves Everywhere Else
```

All pages on http://website.com also exist on http://website.com/international, so that:

```
http://website.com/about-page/
http://website.com/international/about-page/
```

So that when users in America go to http://website.com/about-page/, they're redirected to http://website.com/international/about-page/

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to install libraries (or maybe you don't need it if you have it already installed) I'd encourage you to use [GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/es/book.geoip.php) (you can find it as a [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip)). This is the fastest and easyest way to query about the user's conutry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to read the IP address of the user and map it to the country.

For more information refer to:

http://www.phptutorial.info/iptocountry/the_script.html